# Convert HTML to string, then Find and Replace

Tags: html, string, vba, replace, notepad++

I've searched extensively on this subject and haven't been able to find just what I've been looking for... so here I go!

Basically, I have 2 HTML Files. 1, I export from excel to HTML each day. The 2nd file, has addition code/CSS for table headers and formats as well as a scroll bar and search function. What I do, is copy the necessary bits out of the exported file into the 2nd file so it updates with the latest data. The 2nd file then links in to a larger web page on the company intranet for staff to see their results.

I have an entire automated system in place, and how I have been currently accomplishing this is to use VBA to open Notepad++ (used as my HTML editor) and then manually make these changes. I have recorded a macro within Notepad++ to do the changes automatically using "CTRL F1" as the command, but VBA doesn't work well with the Sendkeys function when I use the shell command to open Notepad++ so it hasn't been a viable solution for automation.

I then researched some more and came across the below code which I have amended to suit my needs, to bypass Notepad++ altogether and turn the HTML into a string. Problem is, it isn't just 1 word I am needing to find and replace, it's 2 entire and separate sections of code. I thought I could use wildcards but it doesn't seem to want to work. Any help that will allow me to replace an entire block of HTML code with another, using excel VBA would be an absolute lifesaver. Thanks in advance!

PS: The below code works as written because I remove the wildcard so it's just finding a couple of words on 1 line and replacing it with the entire code from the source file. I need to be able to replace and entire section, with a specified section from the source file as well

```
Sub Find_Replace2()
Dim sTempSource As String, sTempDest As String
'Dim sTemp As String
Dim sBuf As String
Dim iFileNum As Integer
Dim sFileName As String

'locations of html files, sourcefile goes into destfile
Dim htmlSourcefile As String: htmlSourcefile = "I:\The Hub\Pages\Statistics\Incentive\STB Incentive\STB League2.html"
Dim htmlDestfile As String: htmlDestfile = "I:\The Hub\Pages\Statistics\Incentive\STB League - Copy.html"

sFileName = htmlDestfile

'Opens the above files, and converts them to big long strings
iFileNum = FreeFile
Open htmlDestfile For Input As iFileNum
Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
    Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
    sTempDest = sTempDest & sBuf & vbCrLf
Loop
Close iFileNum

iFileNum = FreeFile
Open htmlSourcefile For Input As iFileNum
Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
    Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
    sTempSource = sTempSource & sBuf & vbCrLf
Loop
Close iFileNum

'find and replace on string
sTempDest = Replace(sTempDest, "<!--Start of VBA insert -->", "<!--Start of VBA insert -->" & sTempSource & "<!--End of VBA insert -->")

'saves string back off as original file
iFileNum = FreeFile
Open sFileName For Output As iFileNum
Print #iFileNum, sTempDest
Close iFileNum

End Sub
```

Comment: how is the excel output structured, as table(s)?

Comment: Yes. It's like a league table of various stats where each employee and their various stats are on 1 row. I need to copy and replace about 100 lines of HTML formatting code into the destination file (where the CSS code is set up for scrolling etc...) and then  another 10000 lines of the actual new and updated data for all the individuals

Comment: Maybe you're going about it the wrong way, would it be better not to adjust the CSS file to get data from the work book itself?  I would suggest looking at `document.getlementsbytagname("TABLE")` and then insert something like `document.getlementsbytagname("TABLE")(0).innerHtml`

Comment: Hey again. I don't suppose you can elaborate a little bit? I am very much a junior when it comes to HTML coding. This is something I have been working at for so long, and have finally just reached out here for some help. It's the last piece of the puzzle that will allow for my daily updated to be fully timed and automated

Answer (score 0):

The replace function will not work as you have it.  The following code gets dest file code before > "!--insert vba....>" here in one text string, then it gets everything after  "!--end insert vba..." in another text string

And we get only the table from the source file. (given that the table end tag is

```
</table>.
```

I saved a table to html and that is how my Excel ended the table.)

So we add together Dest1 + source table + dest2 for the final page.

I have it saving the file to a tester.html file so it won't ruin your original file until you have had the chance to test it.

```
Sub Find_Replace2()
Dim sTempSource As String, sTempDest As String, sTempDest1 As String, sTempDest2 As String
Dim sSource1 As Long, sSource2 As Long, sTempSource2 As String
Dim point1 As Long, point2 As Long, point3 As Long, point4 As Long

Dim sBuf As String
Dim iFileNum As Integer

'locations of html files, sourcefile goes into destfile
Dim htmlSourcefile As String: htmlSourcefile = "I:\The Hub\Pages\Statistics\Incentive\STB Incentive\STB League2.html"
Dim htmlDestfile As String: htmlDestfile = "I:\The Hub\Pages\Statistics\Incentive\STB League - Copy.html"

'Opens the above files, and converts them to big long strings
iFileNum = FreeFile
Open htmlDestfile For Input As iFileNum
Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
    Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
    sTempDest = sTempDest & sBuf & vbCrLf
Loop
Close iFileNum

iFileNum = FreeFile
Open htmlSourcefile For Input As iFileNum
Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
    Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
    sTempSource = sTempSource & sBuf & vbCrLf
Loop
Close iFileNum

point3 = InStr(1, sTempSource, "<table") - 1
point4 = InStr(point3, sTempSource, "</table>") + 8
sTempSource2 = Mid(sTempSource, point3, point4 - point3)


point1 = InStr(1, sTempDest, "<!--Start of VBA insert -->") + 27
point2 = InStr(point1, sTempDest, "<!--End of VBA insert -->")
sTempDest1 = Mid(sTempDest, 1, point1)
sTempDest1 = sTempDest1 & sTempSource2
sTempDest2 = sTempDest1 & Mid(sTempDest, point2, Len(sTempDest) - point2)


'saves string back to a tester file
iFileNum = FreeFile
Open "I:\The Hub\Pages\Statistics\Incentive\tester.html" For Output As iFileNum
Print #iFileNum, sTempDest2
Close iFileNum

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey John, thanks sooooo much for this, you're a genius and this actually does make more sense for sure. I'd have never come across this myself! When I ran this code though, the bottom  line of the 2nd last section...   "sTempDest2 = sTempDest1 & Mid(sTempDest, point2, Len(sTempDest) - point2)" have an error "Run Time 2, Invalid Procedure Call or argument".   I've tried to have a play with it but I'm honestly not sure where to start. I am sure it's probably something very simply but I wanted to make sure before I start adding the 2nd replacement option to this code. Thanks again, very much

Comment: I have been trying to wade through this to figure out what the issue is. I don't have an answer as yet but I have some more info. For example, when I step into the code and hover over "point3" and "point4", I get 673 and 11592 as a result, which makes sense as that's the nuber of characters in the string they are.  When I do the same thing for "point1" & "point2", the result is 27 (because of the +27 at the end of that line of code) and 0 respectively.

Comment: For some reason it's not picking up this string in the same way as the other once, which I assume is having knock on effects, as "sTempDest" shows = "" when I hover over it, but the other ones all show the HTML string. Hopefully this helps! Thanks again, it's truly appreciated!

Comment: Hang on, i am doing additional testing and it appears to be working. No idea what happened between the above comments and now, but I'll take it! Will report back soon!

Comment: Got it!! Thanks again, so much!

Comment: It's dependent on finding exactly "<!--Start of VBA insert -->" and exactly "<!--End of VBA insert -->".  If these change you will have to change the code to match the new text.  The important thing is understanding how and where to split the destination file so we can add the table within the middle.  I wonder if you could make these changes more easily using javascript since you have edit control of the html files.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Find_Replace2()
Dim sTempSource As String, sTempDest As String, sTempDest1 As String, sTempDest2 As String, sTempDest3 As String

Dim sTempSource2 As String, sTempSource3 As String
Dim point1 As Long, point2 As Long, point3 As Long, point4 As Long, point5 As Long, point6 As Long, point7 As Long, point8 As Long

Dim sBuf As String
Dim iFileNum As Integer

'locations of html files, sourcefile goes into destfile
Dim htmlSourcefile As String: htmlSourcefile = "I:\The Hub\Pages\Statistics\Incentive\STB Incentive\STB League2.html"
Dim htmlDestfile As String: htmlDestfile = "I:\The Hub\Pages\Statistics\Incentive\STB League - Copy.html"

'Opens the above files, and converts them to big long strings
iFileNum = FreeFile
Open htmlDestfile For Input As iFileNum
Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
    Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
    sTempDest = sTempDest & sBuf & vbCrLf
Loop
Close iFileNum

iFileNum = FreeFile
Open htmlSourcefile For Input As iFileNum
Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
    Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
    sTempSource = sTempSource & sBuf & vbCrLf
Loop
Close iFileNum

point3 = InStr(1, sTempSource, "<!--table")
point4 = InStr(point3, sTempSource, "-->") + 3
    sTempSource2 = Mid(sTempSource, point3, point4 - point3)

point7 = InStr(1, sTempSource, "</tr>")
point8 = InStr(point7, sTempSource, "<!--END OF OUTPUT FROM EXCEL PUBLISH AS WEB PAGE WIZARD-->") + 58
    sTempSource3 = Mid(sTempSource, point7, point8 - point7)

point1 = InStr(1, sTempDest, "<!--Start of VBA insert -->") + 27
point2 = InStr(point1, sTempDest, "<!--End of VBA insert -->") - 1
point5 = InStr(1, sTempDest, "<!--Start of VBA insert2 -->") + 28
point6 = InStr(point5, sTempDest, "<!--End of VBA insert2 -->") - 1
sTempDest1 = Mid(sTempDest, 1, point1)
sTempDest1 = sTempDest1 & sTempSource2
sTempDest2 = sTempDest1 & Mid(sTempDest, point2, point5 - point2)
sTempDest2 = sTempDest2 & sTempSource3
        sTempDest3 = sTempDest2 & Mid(sTempDest, point6, Len(sTempDest) - point6)

'saves string back to a tester file
iFileNum = FreeFile
Open "I:\The Hub\Pages\Statistics\Incentive\STB League - Copy.html" For Output As iFileNum
Print #iFileNum, sTempDest3
Close iFileNum

End Sub
```